# Append the content of an anchor's link(href) to a div

Tags: jquery

I have a link:

```
<a href="http://tinyurl.com/cmst6r3>Link1</a>
```

Now I want to fetch the content of whatever this link contains, and append it to a div...

```
<a class="link" href="http://tinyurl.com/cmst6r3>Link1</a>
<br />
<div id="content"></div>
```

So the jQuery will look something like this:

```
$('a.link').attr('href').clone().appendTo('div#content');
```

But this does not work

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rudac/2/
How do i do this?

Comment: Just a note that your anchor tag `href` attributes have no closing `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the content of the link to the div

```
$('#content').load($('a.link').attr('href'))
```

If you want to display the link

```
$('#content').html($('a.link').attr('href'))
```

Comment: cool thanks. But by clicking on the link the default function of the anchor tag(to open the link) overrides the jquery of just appending the content of the link to the div

Comment: Or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kQf6Y/2/ but need to keep in my Same Origin Policy

Comment: @DavidVanStaden check http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TZSvb/1/ it may not work because the urls loaded violates [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) restrictions

Comment: As I said it is because the urls violate same origin policy restrictions

Comment: did you check my fiddle...Can you see what the issue is?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden yes I did there also you have same problem, because `load` uses ajax which adheres to same origin policy and there are other problems also like you are loading the contents to the `a` element not to the div

Comment: yes I saw that I am loading it in the wrong element. So what you are telling me is that is not possible?

Comment: yes, if your page domain and the links domain are different then I think you are out of luck

Comment: @DavidVanStaden For a working same check this http://plnkr.co/edit/DUSrZHJD9H37s6u2aRmN?p=preview

Comment: OK, why does the following not work then? How does one do this then? There must be a way, certainly

Comment: Probably you need to read and understand Same Origin Policy to understand this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You can show the contents of whatever the link references with an `iframe`. By using `return false` in the `click` function, the browser will not be directed to the anchor's destination.

I've edited yours to show you what I mean:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rudac/23/

Comment: `.attr` will only give the attribute for the first element in the set of matched `link` classes.

Comment: The original link disappears when I click on the link...I just want it to append its href content(clone it) to the cpntent div.Could you check my updated fiddle please. The clicking of the link interferes with my jquery

Comment: Inside the `.click()` function `return false;` prevents the browser from following the `a` tag's `href`.

Comment: @DavidVanStaden I've updated my answer with a demo of what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: I did add that. It still does not append my link content to the div. Have you actually tried running my fiddle?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden I've edited my answer, hopefully it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

To append

```
$('#content').appendTo($('a.link').attr('href'));
```

To replace

```
 $('#content').html($('a.link').attr('href'));
```